# PDFsharp bitmap size

Tags: vb.net, pdfsharp

I'm using PDFsharp library to transform a control into a PDF file. The problem is that the bitmap image, even if I set height and width and the format is A4, does not fill the view in Adobe Reader.
I also tried to set the parameters manually from DPI but it does not work. The script is:

```
 Dim docum As New PdfDocument()
    For i As Integer = 0 To FoglioFattura1.listaPagIndex.Count - 1
        Dim memImage = New Bitmap(FoglioFattura1.Width, FoglioFattura1.Height) 'A4Size
        FoglioFattura1.DrawToBitmap(memImage, New Rectangle(0, 0, FoglioFattura1.Width, FoglioFattura1.Height))

        Dim oPage As New PdfPage()
        oPage.Orientation = PageOrientation.Portrait
        oPage.Size = PageSize.A4
        'oPage.TrimMargins.Left = 30
        'oPage.TrimMargins.Top = 50
        docum.Pages.Add(oPage)

        Dim xgr As XGraphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(oPage)
        Dim img As XImage = XImage.FromGdiPlusImage(memImage)
        xgr.DrawImage(img, 0, 0)
        Next
```

These are the dimensions of the document, I have hidden the content for privacy reasons. I want the document fill the view.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you call `DrawImage` without specifying the destination size of the image in the PDF. Add Width and Height to the `DrawImage` call and the image will be drawn in the size you specify.

PDFs have no DPI. The size if the PDF page is given in Points - and Points are not pixels.
See also:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)